Turn the Year columns into a one column with the years a feature using Pandas
I have a file with the area burned due to wildfires by month (rows) and Years as columns. The numbers in the dataset represent the area burned in hectares.
It looks like this:

How I can convert the dataset so I get the Years as a Feature using Pandas?
I want the output to look like this:



Jurisdiction
Month
Year
Area Burned




British Columbia
Jan
1990
4000


Ontario
Feb
1998
100



I honestly couldn't figure out a solution for this.

melt or stack (depending on the exact input)

You'd probably have to also skip the first row when reading in the spreadsheet
